# How to change the second init argument in inheritance Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, properties, instance

```py
class window1():
    def __init__(self,height=2,width=9):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width


class window2(window1):
    def __init__(self,width):
        super().__init__(width)


a = window2(100)
print(a.height)
print(a.width)
```

Is it possible to just change the `width` value in `window2` class once we inherit it from `window1` class? I have tried this, so far when I typed this code and run, the only value that start to change is the `height` although I specifically mention the instances `a = window2(100)` to just change the width.

Comment: Pass it as a keyword argument. `super().__init__(width=width)` That's all. It's the same as having `def fun(x=1, y=2, z=3): print(x, y, z)` and running `fun(42)` vs  `fun(y=42)`

Comment: Brilliant !! Been wondering , Thank Youuuuuuuuu. lemme accept this ans

Comment: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ recommends using keyword-only parameters with `__init__`, both so that the end user is force to use keyword arguments to avoid ambiguity over which arguments belong to which positional parameter, and to avoid needing to duplicate parameters in a child-class method. `window2.__init__` could be defined, for example, as `def __init__(self, **kwargs): kwargs['height'] = 2; super().__init__(**kwargs)`.